# Syntax error in UPDATE Statement can't find the solution

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having some trouble updating my table in access through the following code:

```
Update = "UPDATE formation " & _
            "SET AREA = '" & Me.AREA & "', " & _
            "TYPE = '" & Me.TYPE & "', " & _
            "TEAM = '" & Me.TEAM & "', " & _
            "PRIORITY = '" & Me.PRIORITY & "', " & _
            "PROCESS = '" & Me.PROCESSO & "', " & _
            "NUMBER = " & Me.NumForm.Value & "', " & _
            "SUPERVISOR = '" & Me.SUPERVISOR & "', " & _
            "Cc = '" & Me.mailCc & "', " & _
            "STATUS = 'SUBMITED', " & _
            "USER_UPDATE = '" & newFormationUser & "', " & _
            "DATA_STATUS_NOW = '" & Now() & "' " & _
         "WHERE ID = " & Str(NewFormationID)

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL Update
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

NumForm is a ComboBox of numbers 1 to 15.
I've tried to redo query, redo code, remake table with no luck in solving.
Read over and over again to find errors in typo or even in code.

Can you guys help me?
Thank you,
Diogo

Comment: I think you missed single quote `'` in this line `"NUMBER = " & Me.NumForm.Value & "', " & _`. after `=` you need to add `'`

Comment: Saw that, was a mistake, since it is an integer, there is no need for the quote, took it off but same error.

Comment: shouldn't Str(NewFormationID) be encapsulated in single quotes for the WHERE clause?

Comment: @user3479671 Assuming it's numerical, which IDs usually are, no, it shouldn't, and doing so would cause an error. Casting it to a string doesn't hurt, since you're concatenating it to a string and that casts it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong with that statement, but they can all be fixed using parametrization.

First, the missed quote, everyone saw that.

Second, you're setting a column equal to `Now()`, but not using the proper date formatting, and not using date delimiters (`#`).

Third, you're using apostrophes to delimit strings, but not testing if the strings themselves contain apostrophes, inviting unpredictable and hard to diagnose errors.

Also, `Number` is a keyword, that should be enclosed in `[]` brackets.

You should use parametrization, then most of these errors can't occur:

```vb
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "UPDATE formation " & _
            "SET AREA = ?, " & _
            "TYPE = ?, " & _
            "TEAM = ?, " & _
            "PRIORITY = ?, " & _
            "PROCESS = ?, " & _
            "[NUMBER] = ?, " & _
            "SUPERVISOR = ?, " & _
            "Cc = ?, " & _
            "STATUS = 'SUBMITED', " & _
            "USER_UPDATE = ?, " & _
            "DATA_STATUS_NOW = ? " & _
            "WHERE ID = ?")
qd.Parameters(0) = Me.AREA
qd.Parameters(1) = Me.TYPE
qd.Parameters(2) = Me.TEAM 
qd.Parameters(3) = Me.PRIORITY
qd.Parameters(4) = Me.PROCESSO 
qd.Parameters(5) = Me.NumForm.Value
qd.Parameters(6) = Me.SUPERVISOR 
qd.Parameters(7) = Me.mailCc 
qd.Parameters(8) = newFormationUser 
qd.Parameters(9) = Now() 
qd.Parameters(10) = NewFormationID
qd.Execute
```

Comment: Tried to test your idea, but still got the update syntax error. He doesn't pass by the update. Doesn't reach the parameters part.

Comment: Did you try the latest version? Hard to fix all errors if there are more than 3

Comment: Saw now the edited version of your answer, i'll test it now

Comment: Yup that solved the problem, also the keyword Number was the main problem, tried on both ways to see if it would work and it went smoothly. Appreciated! Never knew that Number was a keyword to VBA, still got a lot to learn it seems.

Comment: The [SQL reserved words](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff845663.aspx) list is a good resource. It's quite a long list.

Comment: @DiogoMartins for the record, the *main problem* was the string-concatenation of what should have been parameters. [**This is serious business**](https://xkcd.com/327/), in DBA-land it's called an *SQL Injection vulnerability*, and it leads to all kinds of problems. As for the square-bracketed name, it's not a bad idea to *systematically* add them to every table & field name in your SQL strings.

Comment: I've got to admit that I even put it on SQL but there wasn't any kind of keyword "enlightnment" on NUMBER, will need to learn more keywords it seems. @Mat'sMug thanks for the tip ahah and for now onward i'll systematically will add them to every table & field name!

Comment: Awesome! #OneMoreSavedSoul